# How can I show one user control and hide the rest in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am using windows forms.

I have `Form1` with 20 `buttons` and 20 `user controls`. What I am trying to do is:

When I click `button1` `user control1` shows up and the rest of `user controls` hide, click `button2` `user control2` shows up and the rest of `user controls` hide, click `button3` `user control3` shows up and the rest of `user controls` hide and so on. I can use `UserControl.visible = True` to show one `user control` and hide the rest by setting the rest of `user controls visibility = False` but I do not want to write too much code.

So instead I used the following simple code to show only one `user control` at time when relevant `button` is clicked and hide the rest of `user controls`, but this code did not work it runs with no error but the `user controls` still visible .

Anyone knows why this code did not show `one user control` and hide the rest? I will be happy to hear other ideas too. Thank you

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl .GetType() == typeof(UserControl))
        {
            ctrl .Visible = false;
        }
    }
    UserControl1.visible = True;
}
```

Comment: Maybe because it is a nested control. Currently your loop only goes through the top controls. If one `control.Controls`  isn't empty those child controls are ignored. You could use a recusive method. Have you used the debugger? Is `ctrl .Visible = false` executed at all?

Comment: Instead of  ctrl .Visible = false; maybe  ctrl .IsVisible = false;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your code is not working as expected is this condition:

```
if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(UserControl))
```

`GetType()` returns the actual type which never will be `UserControl`, but some derived from it.

Use the following instead

```
if (ctrl is UserControl)
```

Answer (score 3):

`Button` has a property [`Tag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx). Save your `UserControl` references in tag property for all buttons:

```
button1.Tag = UserControl1;
button2.Tag = UserControl2;
button3.Tag = UserControl3;
//and so on...
//you can do it FormLoad event handler
```

Now subscribe all buttons to single `Click` event:

```
button1.Click += button1_Click; //I am using "button1_Click" for all buttons
button2.Click += button1_Click;
button3.Click += button1_Click;
```

Now the main thing is here:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;  //cast the sender

    //hide all user controls
    foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl .GetType() == typeof(UserControl))
        {
            ctrl .Visible = false;
        }
    }

    //show the usercontrol saved in "Tag" of the current button
    (btn.Tag as UserControl).Visible = True;
}
```

**Note:** I have not compiled this code, if you get any error. Please let me know.

Comment: Or you can just tag the buttons and the user controls with a number (1, 2, 3, ...) and hide all user controls except the one with the matching tag (`userControl.Tag == (sender as Button).Tag` ).

Comment: Yeah that could work as well. But the main point was to use a single event handler for all buttons.

Answer (score 2):

This code worked a treat for me:

```
    var pairs = new[]
    {
        new { Button = button1, UserControl = userControl1 },
        new { Button = button2, UserControl = userControl2 },
        new { Button = button3, UserControl = userControl3 },
        new { Button = button4, UserControl = userControl4 },
        new { Button = button5, UserControl = userControl5 },
        new { Button = button6, UserControl = userControl6 },
        new { Button = button7, UserControl = userControl7 },
        new { Button = button8, UserControl = userControl8 },
        new { Button = button9, UserControl = userControl9 },
        new { Button = button10, UserControl = userControl10 },
        new { Button = button11, UserControl = userControl11 },
        new { Button = button12, UserControl = userControl12 },
        new { Button = button13, UserControl = userControl13 },
        new { Button = button14, UserControl = userControl14 },
        new { Button = button15, UserControl = userControl15 },
        new { Button = button16, UserControl = userControl16 },
        new { Button = button17, UserControl = userControl17 },
        new { Button = button18, UserControl = userControl18 },
        new { Button = button19, UserControl = userControl19 },
        new { Button = button20, UserControl = userControl20 },
    };

    foreach (var pair in pairs)
    {
        pair.UserControl.Visible = false;
        pair.Button.Click += (s, e2) =>
        {
            foreach (var pair2 in pairs) { pair2.UserControl.Visible = false; }
            pair.UserControl.Visible = true;
        };
    }
```

I purposefully create a list of button/user control pairs so that they are hard-coded and I don't have to go looking for them by name. It's better this way for refactoring and verifying your code.

Then the first `foreach` loop just wires up the click event which makes all of the user controls invisible except for the paired user control.

Just pop this code in your `Form_Load` event handler.